# What does 0! means in vb6.0?

Tags: vb6

I have found a code where in IF condition 0! compared to the user entered value. I tried with '0!' value in immediate window and it is returning 0 only.

So, I want to to know what '!' sign exactly for??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the complete statement?

Comment: Statement is -   If gfPALD1 = 0 And gfPALD2 <> 0! Then

Comment: Vaguely related: [What is difference between Command$ and Command in VB 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4527103)

Comment: Also vaguely related [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373135/significance-of-an-ampersand-in-vb6-function-name](Significance of an ampersand in VB6 function name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek(v=vs.80).aspx

It forces the type of the literal 0 to be Single.

See also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dzy06xhf.aspx about appended type characters.

0! indicates it is a floating point number (Single) instead of an integer.

```
typeOf 0! is Single
typeOf 0 is Integer
```

Comment: Thanks for quick replies. Yes '!' signify datatype as single. We can enforce the datatype for variables using char or sing. Here value(i.e. 0) plus ! mentioned, so what 0!(zero+!) means exactly?

Comment: It means 0 as represented by the 'single' data type