# Convert vb6 code to vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am trying to get this PID control code into my VB.net project, but am a bit clueless about all the exclamation marks.  Can someone explain to me how to implement this code in VB.NET?

```
Dim Er!, Derivative!, Proportional!

    Static Olderror!, Cont!, Integral!
    Static Limiter_Switch%
    Limiter_Switch% = 1

    Er = setpoint - process

    If ((Cont >= 1 And Er > 0) Or (Cont <= 0 And Er < 0) Or (Integ >= 9999)) Then
        Limiter_Switch = 0
    Else
        Limiter_Switch = 1
    End If
    Integral = Integral + Gain / Integ * Er * deltaT * Limiter_Switch

    Derivative = Gain * deriv * (Er - Olderror) / deltaT

    Proportional = Gain * Er

    Cont = Proportional + Integral + Derivative
    Olderror = Er

    If (Cont > 1) Then
        Cont = 1
    End If
    If (Cont < 0) Then
        Cont = 0
    End If
    Return ()
```

Comment: See this question/ answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373135/significance-of-an-ampersand-in-vb6-function-name/9373296#9373296

Comment: To add to what the other answers have said, this technique of declaring variable type by a symbol is called a sigil: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In VB6, certain suffixes can be added to specify a variable type.  For instance:

```
Dim x%
```

Is the same as:

```
Dim x As Integer
```

The suffixes are still supported in VB.NET, but they are **widely discouraged**.  Here is the list of possible suffixes:

- `$` is the suffix for `String`
- `%` is the suffix for `Integer`
- `&` is the suffix for `Long`
- `!` is the suffix for `Single`
- `#` is the suffix for `Double`
- `@` is the suffix for `Currency` (now `Decimal` in .NET)

VB6 did not provide suffix characters for all of the core data types.  For instance, there is no valid suffix character for `Boolean`, `Date`, or `Short`.  Even in VB6, many people recommended always using `As` in all variable declarations, but there were still many people who recommended using the suffixes, where available, because they provided some additional pre-compile type-checking which was often beneficial.

So, to convert that code to .NET, you'd want to replace the suffix symbols in any variable declaration lines with an `As ...` clause, specifying the equivalent type, for istance, instead of this:

```
Dim Er!, Derivative!, Proportional!
Static Olderror!, Cont!, Integral!
Static Limiter_Switch%
```

You'd convert it to this:

```
Dim Er, Derivative, Proportional As Single
Static OldError, Cont, Integral As Single
Static Limiter_Switch As Integer
```

And then, where ever a suffix symbol appears when a variable is being used, outside of a declaration line, you can just remove the symbol.  For instance, instead of this:

```
Limiter_Switch% = 1
```

You'd convert it to this:

```
Limiter_Switch = 1
```

Bear in mind, when converting types from VB6 to VB.NET, that the numeric types in VB.NET are larger.  So for instance, `Integer` in VB6 is 16-bit, but in VB.NET, `Integer` is 32-bit.  So, technically, the equivalent in VB.NET, for a VB6 `Integer` is `Short`.  Typically, it doesn't matter, and you just want to use `Integer` for `Integer`, but if the number of bits matters, you need to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

These symbols specified the variable type in older versions of MS Basic, up to VB6.
% = Integer, &=Long, !=Single, #=Double, @=Currency, $=string

Comment: They still are valid in vb.net also

Comment: They must date back to BASIC-80! If there's one thing Microsoft do well, it's backwards compatibility!

Comment: @peter That's a really ironic comment given this question is about converting VB6 to VB.Net! :P